# Why do I get "invalid coin denomination" when using Starport with the CosmosSDK

Tags: token, tendermint, cosmos-sdk

I am using Starport (https://github.com/tendermint/starport) to bootstrap my Cosmos SDK blockchain. I only want one Token for staking and usage of the blockchain.

This is my `config.yml` file

```
version: 1
accounts:
  - name: user1
    coins: ["120000aphoton"]
  - name: user2
    coins: ["1000aphoton"]
validator:
  name: user1
  staked: "100000aphoton"
```

When trying to run the daemon of the blockchain, I receive the error

```
panic: invalid coin denomination: failed to execute message; message index: 0
```

What is wrong with my coin denomination and what do I need to change / be aware of when customizing my token in the `config.yml`? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to configure the staking module to accept aphoton as a bond denomination. This can be done by adding the following to config.yml:

```
genesis:
  app_state:
    staking:
      params:
        bond_denom: "aphoton"
```